# Cannot build with AVFoundation AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, xcode5

I am working with ios project that uses AVFoundation framework. i work with xcode5 and ios7. after adding the framework from build phases and importing it and start building the project. xcode gives me error:

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/ahmadnasser/Desktop/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation, missing required architecture armv7s in file /Users/ahmadnasser/Desktop/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioPlayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RegistrationViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

the code is :

```
NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"whistle" ofType:@"mp3"]];
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:nil];
[audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:INFINITY];
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[audioPlayer play];
```

there's a note that when i just import and define an object

```
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
[audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:INFINITY];
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[audioPlayer play];
```

the code compile with no problem. I really need help

Answer (score 0):

Add the CoreVideo and CoreMedia frameworks

It seems you haven't added CFNetwork.framework and Security.framework,AVFoundation framework,SystemConfiguration.framework,MediaPlayer frameworks to your project. Add them in Xcode at the "libraries to link" section, and everything should be fine.

Or

Solved this by changing Library Search Paths in Build Settings to

**./Classes "$(SRCROOT)/Classes"**

Just in case anyone else finds this and wants to give it a try.

EDIT: Just to add, I had this same problem again just now actually. And the reason it happened for me is because I changed the folder name that sits with the .xcodeproj file. So In a folder on my mac I had a directory called App Name and file called App Name.xcodeproj. I changed the directory App Name to something different and despite updating the build settings in xcode, still had the same problem. What I had to do was

Right Click App Name.xcodeproj
Click Show Package Contents
Open project.pbxproj
Then cmd + f (search) and enter App Name, I think there were just two places and they were 1/3 of the way down the page, called name and immediately below, path. Change them to the new directory name, save and reopen your project and all should be well.

Comment: ld: framework not found SystemConfiguration
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)